# Does divergence in $H^1_0$ implies uniform divergence in finite dimensional subspaces of $H^1_0$ whose elements are continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

If $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathcal{B}_\Omega$ is the set of Borel subsets of $\Omega$, $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ in the Sobolev space $H^1(\Omega)$ with respect to the Sobolev norm and $V$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $H^1_0(\Omega)$ whose elements are continuous function, is it true that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$\lim_{\|u\|\rightarrow\infty,  u\in V}\left(\sup_{\Omega_0\in\ \mathcal{B}_\Omega, \mu(\Omega_0)>\delta}\left(\inf_{x\in\Omega_0}|u(x)|\right)\right)=+\infty?,$$
i.e.
$$\exists \delta >0, \forall M>0, \exists R>0, \forall u\in V, (\|u\|>R)\implies \left(\exists\Omega_0\in\mathcal{B}_\Omega,(\mu(\Omega_0)>\delta)\land(\inf_{x\in\Omega_0}|u(x)|>M)\right)?$$
Or, sequentially: is it true that for each finite dimensional vector subspace of $H^1_0(\Omega)$ made of continuous functions, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $M>0$ there exists $R>0$ such that for each sequence $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset V$ diverging in $H^1_0(\Omega)$, if $N\in\mathbb{N}$ is such that $\forall n \ge N, \|u_n\|\ge R$ then there exists a sequence  $(\Omega_n)_{n\ge N}\subset\mathcal{B}_\Omega$ such that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, \mu(\Omega_n)>\delta$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, \forall x\in\Omega_0, |u_n(x)|\ge M$?

Obviously the result is false if we remove the finite dimensional condition, as we can see taking a sequence of bounded continuous functions oscillating more and more... however I think that this should be the only obstruction to get the result and that somehow the finite dimensional condition should rule out this phenomenon, but I'm having trouble proving it...

Comment: What prevents you from choosing $V$ to be a one-dimensional space generated by a single function that is strictly positive on some small neighborhood $\Omega_0$ of $\Omega$? Then the infimum over $\Omega_0$ is positive and goes to infinity as the norm of this function is scaled up.

Comment: I can't choose $V$... $V$ is arbitrary

Comment: I see. Also, just to be clear, your limit is over the infimum of all $u \in V$ with at least a certain norm, yes?

Comment: The limit is taken in the Sobolev norm restricted to $V$

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't clarify it enough. Your limit has two quantifiers in it (the size of the norm, and the choice of element of $V$).

Comment: $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ is a normed vector space, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the Sobolev norm. The limit is taken in this normed vector space as the norm goes to $\infty$

Comment: Perhaps let me rephrase my question. Your limit can be viewed as a sequential limit of the form $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = + \infty$. What are the elements of the sequence $a_n$?

Comment: $\lim_{\|u\|\rightarrow\infty,  u\in V}\inf_{x\in\Omega_0}|u(x)|=+\infty$ if and only if $\forall M>0, \exists R>0, \forall u\in V, (\|u\|>R)\implies(\inf_{x\in\Omega_0}|u(x)|>M)$

Comment: In that case, a counter example would be $V$ containing at least two functions $u_1, u_2$ supported on disjoint neighborhoods. Then no matter what $\Omega_0$ you pick, at least one of $u_1, u_2$ will be zero somewhere.

Comment: you are perfectly right: thanks for pointing it out. When stating the problem, I had in my mind something different... I'll think better about it and I'll edit the question accordingly

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong edited... hope it is clear and that I don't make another silly mistake in capturing the idea